# Appending multiple inputs to submit in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, append

I'm having trouble to append multiple inputs. I am reading a list with items and values and want to submit them over Javascript (POST), but I can't figure out why this doesn't want to work. I tried in several ways, finally I came up with this, but it doensn't want to iterate over it and throw an error:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.action = "submitform.php";
form.method = "post";
form.target = "_blank";
input = [];

var kvarray = document.getElementsByClassName('ua_mattext');

    for (var i = 0; i < kvarray.length; i++) {

        var fieldname = kvarray[i].id;
        var fieldvalue = kvarray[i].value;

        input[i] = "input_" + i;
        document.createElement(input[i]);
        input[i].type = "hidden";
        input[i].name = fieldname;
        input[i].value = fieldvalue;
        form.appendChild(input[i]);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: brusharr.length???? and `document.createElement(input[i]);` is doing nothing. It does not magically update the array with an input and there is no element with the type `<input_1/>`

Comment: kvarray is going to return a node list (an array-like object containing element nodes). `kvarray[i]` will reference a given element node - - not a name.

Comment: 1st: you are iterating over brusharr instead of kvarray; why?? 2nd:what you pretend to be fieldname is a node object, not a text; 3rd: input[i] is a text, not an input. Review that and rewrite your question, please.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot ... brusharr is the same as kvarray, I renamed half of it in SO... Sorry - Corrected myself in the edited post

Comment: @sergio0983 Corrected myself in the question and also answered it, since I figured it out. Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by myself. Firstly, I wasn't declaring the `input` variable properly (Forgot the "var " at the beginning)

Secondly, I wasn't setting the `document.createElement()` to the input.

Thirdly, I was naming the input `input_1`,`input_2`, which was invalid. There is only one, which is `input`.

So, now it's working. Below is the corrected code:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.action = "submitform.php";
form.method = "post";
form.target = "_blank";
var input = [];

var kvarray = document.getElementsByClassName('ua_mattext');

    for (var i = 0; i < kvarray.length; i++) {

        var fieldname = kvarray[i].id;
        var fieldvalue = kvarray[i].value;

        input[i] = "input_" + i;
        input[i] = document.createElement("input");
        input[i].type = "hidden";
        input[i].name = fieldname;
        input[i].value = fieldvalue;
        form.appendChild(input[i]);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
  input[i] = "input_" + i;
```

nothing about this line actually creates an input HTML element.  Instead, you can do something like this

```
  input[i] = <input type="hidden" name="${fieldname}" value="${fieldvalue}">
```

which would also have the added benefit of replacing the 3 lines following that one.

p.s: you should also declare input in the beginning by saying:

```
var input = []
```

p.p.s: You should check your assumptions as to what kvarray[i] is equal to.  If you are doing kvarray[i].value in the subsequent line, I doubt that kvarray[i] is going to be a string, which is what you will need it to be in order to set the input's name attribute equal to it.